# JS function parameter "modifiers"

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I stumbled upon some strange JS feature(?) or behavior by accident and I cannot explain or google it.

```js
function foo([a]) { alert(a); };
foo('Those brakets will make me use a string, but only uses the first char');
```

```js
function foo({a}) { alert(typeof a); };
foo('This one will make "a" always be undefined');
```

And there might be more. Does this behavior have a name? Or can anyone explain it?

Comment: both snippets are not working.

Comment: What Browser are you using? The given codesnippets aren't working in my chrome, they just cause exceptions, because the browser isn't expection a "[" or a "{", but a parameter

Comment: It's called destructuring, and is basically the same as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: are you asking what is meaning of result of meaningless expression?

Comment: Both are OK in ES2015, paste them into http://babeljs.io/repl/ and see what's the ES5 equivalent after transpilation.

Comment: @Neutrosider: I am using Chrome 48. They both work for me.

Comment: @FelixKling: Wow, thank you! That's interesting. If you make an answer, I can accept it :)

Comment: @Daniel: In my opinion, the two expressions are _not_ meaningless. They precisely show what I am troubled with.

Comment: @MarcoAlka sorry for my ignorance,i didn't know second one with {}, but is the first option with [] has description